# Getting actual facebook image urls using python flask?

Tags: python, flask

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MjMI.png)I want to write a flask code that downloads 'main' image from urls that contain images.

I have urls like these in my data (text files)

https://www.facebook.com/AnushkaShetty/photos/a.452351745192.374596.210302285192/10158271238825193/?type=3

but their expanded urls don't result in .jpg,.jpeg images. Instead they direct us to a page that contains the desired image.

How do I download images from these urls?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MjMI.png)

Comment: parse the html content and then get the image.

Comment: could you please expain brefly.

Comment: when i run this code it downloads the profile pic of fb post but not the post pic.i need to get Img attribute from html source (i.e as I did for profile image) and get the correct image as needed. from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as ur

urlData = ur.urlopen('https://www.facebook.com/AnushkaShetty/photos/a.452351745192.374596.210302285192/10158271238825193/?type=3')

data = str(urlData.readlines())
bs = BeautifulSoup(data,"lxml")
print(bs)
if imgUrl = bs.findAll('img')[0].get('src')
ur.urlretrieve(imgUrl, "download.jpg")

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Flask (but you can run the code within Flask).

You can use something like [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master), follow redirects and [download the image](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content).